# How to get value from a cell in table C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have table and each row contains a button. If I click the button, I want to retrieve the value from the first column in that particular row. This is my code, how can I do that. Thank you

```
    foreach (var c in list)
        {
            TableRow row = new TableRow();

            TableCell c0 = new TableCell();
            c0.Text = string.Format("<img src='"+c.Movie_poster+ "'/>");
            TableCell c1 = new TableCell();
            c1.Text = c.Name;
            TableCell c2 = new TableCell();
            c2.Text = c.Date.ToStirng();
            TableCell c3 = new TableCell();
            c3.Text = c.desc;
            TableCell c4 = new TableCell();
            c4.Text = c.genre;
            TableCell c5 = new TableCell();


            //Add each string to cell in row
            row.Cells.Add(c0);
            row.Cells.Add(c1);
            row.Cells.Add(c2);
            row.Cells.Add(c3);
            row.Cells.Add(c4);
            row.Cells.Add(c5);

            //Add the row to the table
            Table.Rows.Add(row);
            Button getname = new Button();
            getname.Text = "Reserve";
            getname.Click+= new EventHandler(getname_Click);

            c5.Controls.Add(getname);

        }


    }
    protected void reserve_Click(object sender,EventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = (Button)sender;
        TableRow row = (TableRow)btn.
        string name = row.Cells[1].Text;
        lbl.Text = name;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Before create button you should write a new attribute with Row number.

```
    //Add the row to the table
    Table.Rows.Add(row);
    Button getname = new Button();
    getname.Attributes.Add("idRow", idrow);
    idrow += 1;
    getname.Text = "Reserve";
    getname.Click += new EventHandler(getname_Click);
```

Then in you reserve_Click you should get the row with the ID stored in button attributes

```
 Button btn = (Button)sender;
 int idRow = int.Parse(btn.Attributes["id"]);
 TableRow row = t.Rows[idRow];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the value of the Column to the Button as a `CommandArgument`.

```
Button getname = new Button();
getname.Text = "Reserve";
getname.CommandName = "Reserve";
getname.CommandArgument = "Column Value";
getname.Command += new CommandEventHandler(Button1_Command);
```

And then in the Button Command

```
protected void Button1_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Reserve")
    {
        string columnValue = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. It worked. I replaced "Column Value" with c.Name. Thanks again.